# Maintaining date range calculations across rows without looping

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I have a set of date values in Oracle that I am doing an `ORDER BY START_TIME, STOP_TIME` as in the data sample below.  The column labeled NEXT_START_TIME, as you can see, is retrieved through the LEAD() function.

```
START_TIME      STOP_TIME       NEXT_START_TIME
6/13/2013 5:19  6/13/2013 5:34  6/13/2013 5:19   -- no delay, OK
6/13/2013 5:19  6/13/2013 6:23  6/13/2013 5:39
6/13/2013 5:39  6/13/2013 6:04  6/13/2013 6:23   -- delay? wrong
6/13/2013 6:23  6/13/2013 7:32  6/13/2013 9:18
6/13/2013 9:18  6/13/2013 9:50  6/13/2013 9:44
6/13/2013 9:44  6/13/2013 10:01
```

This data represents assigned jobs.  The difficult task I have is, in the most efficient manner, how to determine if there was any delay in assigning a job.  The first entry represents no delay since the NEXT_START_TIME came before the STOP_TIME.  Only in cases where the NEXT_START_TIME came *after* the STOP_TIME can we consider there to be a delay (as in the third row).
The wrinkle is that even though the third row would seem to indicate a delay, it's not correct.  Even though the NEXT_START_TIME was 6:23 it needs to be aware of the fact that a previous job was still in progress (see the two ***highlighted*** items).
Is there a way to accomplish this without O(N), or worse, iterations?  Right now the use of the LEAD() function is very efficient.
Please ask for clarifications if needed since I realize this may be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `lead()`, you want a cumulative max.  Try using this instead of `lead()`:

```
select START_TIME, STOP_TIME,
       max(stop_time) over (order by start_time) as MaxCumStopTime
from t
```

The `order by` clause instructs Oracle to make this a cumulative statement, which will take the max of any time up to this row.

Comment: Brilliant!  I didn't realize the MAX() would work in that manner.  It seems to take the MAX() up to and including the transition row (where the start_time changes).

Comment: Is it possible to leave NULL values in the STOP_TIME column as NULL and not "overwrite" them with the MAX() value?